# GST/VAT tax. Why some countries return tax to tourists?

Tags: taxes

Some countries return tax to tourists in airports.

I don't understand it. Why is it happening? What was the logic behind the decision? Why is it only related to purchase tax and not to income tax? Why is it so important to preserve original packaging?

It is obviously a sort of segregation and nationalism. Why did people vote for it?

I have heard that European countries are doing it along with Japan, Australia, and maybe some other countries are doing it as well...

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Isn't favoring foreign tourists by not making them pay taxes the opposite of nationalism, which involves favoring citizens or residents of one's own nation, or even more restricted groups? Also, this is much more common than just Japan, Australia, and Europe. You could add the United States, Vietnam, South Africa, Mexico, Argentina....

Comment: The tourists then need to pay import VAT in their home country, unless there is an exception (which there often is, such as a certain free volume). That’s just the way VAT works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL/DR:** You could consider that a traveller buying a good before going home is an export, with the only difference that the export is done by the final consumer. **Exports do not pay sales tax almost everywhere in the world.**

Let's go step by step:

> What was the logic behind the decision?

The state stops getting the VAT/sales tax money, but gets all the other money: the money that goes to the profits of the seller (that are taxed), the salary of the workers (that are taxed, and since they are working they are not using unemployment benefits), the money that pays the rent of the place...

Why target foreign travellers? Because travellers will have the opportunity to buy the same item at their next destination. So there is an incentive to offer them a discount to get their purchase even if you do not get the sales tax; if you do not convince them their money is probably gone for good.

Additionally, even if the price is lower a foreign traveller may have doubts about purchasing an item (things like servicing warranties can be troublesome), so they may need an extra incentive to purchase.

In opposition, a local resident does not usually have the option to purchase the item elsewhere<sup>1</sup> so there is no incentive to offer him sales tax exemptions.

> Why is it only related to purchase tax and not to income tax

??? This is directly related to sales because the objective is to increase sales. The reference to income tax is puzzling, as non-residents do not pay it anyway, and even if it wanted to the state will not have the income information of non-residents to tax them.

> Why is it so important to preserve original packaging?

Probably to avoid fraud and ensure that the item that you claim that you are exporting was bought in the country. Otherwise, I could enter a country with my iPad, buy another iPad, sell the new one to a local (at a discount since I did not pay sales tax) and claim the sales tax when leaving the country. Profit!

> Why did people vote for it?

As usual, "people" do not vote directly on all the issue but they elect representatives who make the decissions. The reasons for such representatives to vote for such laws are explained above.

> It is obviously a sort of segregation and nationalism

I guess you mean "discrimination by reason of nationality". Guess what, discrimination by nationality is the norm for many things. For example, you will not be able to vote in the elections of a country you are not a national of.

<sup>1</sup> If someone tries to order an item from a foreign business and have it shipped to them, sales tax will be applied at customs in most countries that I know of.

Comment: I'd move the bolded portion to the top. That's the headline explanation.